# How to utilize browser caching when loading modules via script tag insertion?

Tags: javascript, caching, module, requirejs

I'm writing a small promise-based module loader. Modules are loaded via `<script>` tag, so if I want to load module `foo`, I'm inserting:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_foo/foo.js"></script>
```

I can fetch the response object being returned by `foo.js` and store it internally in my loader for future requests. All no problem.

But with this setup I'm not using the browser cache - a fetched module will be loaded once, presumably stored in the browser cache AND in addition stored my loader, from where it is served on subsequent requests.

I'm curious how it would be possible to leverage browser caching when inserting modules via `<script>` tags. If I would load something via Ajax any subsequent request would be served from cache, but I don't how this could be doable via script tag insertion.

**Question**:
When inserting script tags, is it possible to utilize the browser cache?

Comment: that caching is invisible but reliable. you can use a manifest for explicit control. check your net tab in dev tools to see what's already happening, you're probably fine just "re-fetching" from a cached copy. trying to maintain your own script cache is more complex than the minor perf gains it could enable.

Comment: but on subsequent request, do I just add more `<script>` tags with the same src?

Comment: if you ask for the same url twice, you normally get a cached copy the 2nd time, unless http headers told the browser something different.

Comment: I see. Give me a few minutes to try.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am running into an issue where loading a script by inserting a script tag does not load from Cache only for Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94

Comment: Hm. Not really, but I have not tried for a while. Currently, I'm just keeping the first scripts response (module) on memory, without making any further requests. I thought about dumping a module from my internal store, once I don't need it anymore, because then, the next time it's needed, a new request is necessary which should then be served from cache. Have to look into this some more, but no time at the moment. Sorry.